# How do you add text to a carousel of images like here in this example

Tags: images

I see nobody really like to answer my questions, I will ask again.

How do I add text to a carousel like in this example image.[image]

Answer (score -1):

It depends. There are various carousel plugins and codes available that allow you to achieve something like that. Can you provide a link of where you saw the carousel in that image.

If you are a developer you can use owl carousel which is very good in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks human being! I will try to add it to wordpress.

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html here's a url of the basic demo. Inside a div you can add whatever you want. So in your case add an image and text and you can achieve something like what you shown.

Comment: Wait, I have to know how to code correct?